# Special characters in Smartsheet API (2.0) - search

Tags: smartsheet-api

Within the API for smartsheet I use the search everything method.

However, when trying to search for 'A01 PXXX' it returns me also rows (and cells) which contain only 'A01' and 'PXXX'. Is there a way to search for the whole searchstring (so including the space character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you URL-encode the space character in the **query** querystring parameter value, it the [Search Everything](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#search-everything) operation should return only results that contain the full string.

For example, I have a sheet that contains these values:

[image: Sheet]

I execute the following request:  `GET https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/search?query=A01%20PXXX`

And the response contains search results for only the two rows that contain the string "A01 PXXX":

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "text": "A01 PXXX",
            "objectType": "row",
            "objectId": 8740290866505604,
            "parentObjectType": "sheet",
            "parentObjectId": 505434269345668,
            "parentObjectName": "Project Plan (Office Timeline Test)",
            "contextData": [
                "Row 20"
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "A01 PXXX",
            "objectType": "row",
            "objectId": 1732072470538116,
            "parentObjectType": "sheet",
            "parentObjectId": 505434269345668,
            "parentObjectName": "Project Plan (Office Timeline Test)",
            "contextData": [
                "Row 17"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "totalCount": 2
}
```

Comment: Late reaction, but appreciated: this works for me. Thanks Kim!

Comment: Thanks for the update, Maaik!  Can you please mark my response as the "accepted answer", so that others may benefit from this info in the future? Thanks!

Comment: Now having the same problem which I a trying to solve in C Sharp. Unicode "\u0020" or "%20" do not seem to work. Anyone ?