# Search method in Smartsheet API 2.0 C Sharp

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

Within the API for smartsheet I use the search everything method.

Already solved in cUrl (check [Special characters in Smartsheet API (2.0) - search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782619/special-characters-in-smartsheet-api-2-0-search)), but within **C-sharp** how can I solve this:

When trying to search for 'A01 PXXX' it returns me also rows (and cells) which contain only 'A01' and 'PXXX'. Is there a way to search for the whole searchstring (so including the space character). Unicode "\u0020" or "%20" do not seem to work. Anyone ?

Comment: From the tests I did last year, I wasn't able to perfom an exact search with the api. Best guess right now would be to perfom the search and then to filter with custom c# code.

Comment: Hi @EtienneMermillod. Yep. Did it but it was just frustrating to see everything works fine and now 'all of a sudden' (by upgrading the SDK) not anymore. I have our development-team checked it out. Seems there was a little bug in the new version, which they solved and tolded Smartsheet Dev-team about it: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-csharp-sdk/pull/116 No reaction however

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting the whole search string in double quotes(i.e. `"\"A01 PXXX\""`)?

Comment: Hi @timwells. Yep. But no result: seems to be a bug. Reported this via Github to Smartsheet: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-csharp-sdk/pull/116